# Firebase messaging in react - access to the background message from react code

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering what is the best practice to handle the background message. This background message is only for show notification? Or I can generate some DOM element based on it or something?

In

```
firebase.messaging.onMessage(...) {...}
```

I have 'react context access' I can dispatch action there or something.

But in SW:

```
setBackgroundMessageHandler(...) {...}
```

I can't.

Docs said (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive)

```
// Handle incoming messages. Called when:
// - a message is received while the app has focus
// - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
//   `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` handler.
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
```

That onMessage should be called when user click on notification. But it doesn't work. I can't get onMessage call when I click on bacground notification. Are there any requirements to 'redirect' payload from setBackgroundMessage to onMessage?

Or just I should pass link in payload, and openWindow with this link?